# {TextMeshPro problem} Coin collecting system that increases coin counter when the player is in contact with the sphere - works with Debug.Log. [Unity]

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, textmeshpro

I made a coin collecting system that increases the number on a counter when the player comes in contact with the "coin" > sphere. I used **Debug.Log** to make sure that the counter works. **It does.** However, When I use TextMeshPro to display that value, it is stuck at zero.

```
public float moneyStart;
public float unit;
public float moneyNow;
public float displayedMoney;
private TextMeshPro textsss;

void Start()
{
    TextMeshPro textsss = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision C_Info)
{
    if (C_Info.collider.tag == "Currency")
    {
        displayedMoney = moneyNow + unit;
        textsss.text = displayedMoney.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

[Visual for the counter stuck at zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI4Ed.png)

***The script is in the TextMeshPro Element***

- Am I using TextMeshPro correctly?
- How can I use it better?
- Are there any errors?
- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass any argument to the `.ToString()` method

```cs
textsss.text = displayedMoney.ToString();
```

And to answer your questions, you are using TextMeshPro correctly, updating the text every time the field `displayedMoney` is getting updated

Comment: After not passing a argument to the ToString, There are no errors that show on the console but the counter is still stuck at 0.

Comment: @TheOdinBorson, where are you printing the value? I don't find it in your code. It would be beneficial if you could post your whole code